# Does Low Options support checkboxes?

Tags: low-search

In [the devotee page](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-options), [Low Options](https://github.com/lodewijk/low_options) has this description

> Low Options displays the list items or options for a given channel
>   field. Compatible with native Select DropDown and Checkboxes fields,
>   as well as Pixel & Tonic's channel fields that use options.

I have looked over the documentation and the plugin itself but nothing seems to point that it supports checkboxes.

Is this correct?

EDIT:

Here is my code

```
<fieldset>
     <label>Pets:</label>
     {exp:low_options:pets}
        {options}
            <label for="{option_label}">{option_label}:</label> <input type="checkbox" name="search:pets[]" value="{option_value}" />
        {/options}
    {/exp:low_options:pets}
</fieldset>
```

"Pets" is a native Dropdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works fine with checkboxes.

For native checkboxes *{option:value}* and *{option:label}* will output the same thing. For the P&T Fieldpack, each one will correspond to the *option : label*.

Comment: I will post my markup code in the question. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Okay, I think I saw may problem. I was using  {option_value} and {option_label} instead of {option:value} and {option:label}